# Bash: Irregular behavior of substrings?

Tags: bash

I have a question about substrings in Bash, which seem irregular to me. Imagine I have `X="Hello World!"`. Then:

```
echo ${X:4} # Prints 'o World!'
echo ${X:(-2)} # Prints 'd!'
```

Why does a positive integer show the **whole string** except for the specified characters, while a negative characters shows **nothing** except for the specified characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2-ways to offset from *end-of-string* in bash. The first uses the index in parenthesis as you have:

```
echo ${X:(-2)} # Prints 'd!'
```

The second leaves a `space` after to `:`

```
echo ${X: -2} # Prints 'd!'
```

Both are offset from *end-of-string*. What is printed is the same for the *positive* and *negative* case. Characters are printed from the *index* to *end-of-string*. In the negative case, you offset from *end-of-string* by `2` and then print all remaining characters *from that index*. (the last 2-chars)

You can prove it to yourself with:

```
echo ${X: -2:1} # Prints 'd'
```

Positive indexes are offset from *beginning-of-string*, negative indexes are offset from *end-of-string*. In both cases what is printed is the remaining characters in the string unless the number of characters to print is specified following a second colon. (e.g. `${var:index:nchars}` )

Answer (score 2):

It works as [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${parameter:offset}
> ${parameter:offset:length}
>
> This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character
> specified by offset. If parameter is ‘@’, an indexed array subscripted
> by ‘@’ or ‘*’, or an associative array name, the results differ as
> described below. **If length is omitted, it expands to the substring of
> the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset
> and extending to the end of the value.** length and offset are
> arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).
>
> **If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter.**
> [..]

(emphasis mine)

So a negative offset is equivalent to its positive offset as below:

```
pos_offset = len_of_str + neg_offset
```

i.e. in your example, `${X:(-2)}` should behaves as `${X:10}` (str_len = 10 and neg_offset = -2, so pos_offset = 10). So both print the *whole string* starting from the specified index.